# Mysql Alter table timing depending on presence of foreign keys

Tags: mysql, indexing, foreign-keys, alter

We have a situation where we have a table A and B, where A has few thousand rows ( approx 50k) and B has few million rows (approx 5M). Table B has a column which points to Table A's primary key. We need to add a column to table A and are concerned that while alter statement runs, it would perhaps have a read lock on table B.

My first question is, is that true, that table B would get locked while altering table A? And if yes, would it be better to drop the foreign key from B to A first then run the alter statements, and recreate the foreign key afterwards.

We are using MySQL 5.5, InnoDB and separate files for each table.

Comment: Personally i would recommend to remove the foreign key constrain when the table size is big. It will slow down the process. And secondly, during an alter table, a copy of the table is made internally and if succeessful the old table is replaced with new one. So read-lock makes sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
set foreign_key_checks = 0;
ALTER TABLE ...;
set foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

You can remove the foreign key, if it is safe to remove permanently.  But removing the foreign key constraint temporarily and then add it again after the `ALTER` statement would be an overhead.